# Python floating point precision sum

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I have the following array in python

`n = [565387674.45, 321772103.48,321772103.48, 214514735.66,214514735.65,
357524559.41]`

if I sum all these elements, I get this:

```
sum(n)
1995485912.1300004
```

But, this sum should be:

> 1995485912.13

In this way, I know about floating point "error". I already used the `isclose()` function from numpy to check the corrected value, but
**how much is this limit? Is there any way to reduce this "error"?**

The main issue here is that the error propagates to other operations, for example, the below assertion must be true:

`assert (sum(n) - 1995485911) ** 100 - (1995485912.13 - 1995485911) ** 100 == 0`.

Comment: Python has `math.fsum` to compute “an accurate floating point sum,” but [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) is vague. It generally returns a better result than simple serial addition, but it will not always return the best result possible in the floating-point format.

Comment: Thanks, this method work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is problem with floating point numbers. One solution is having them represented in string form and using `decimal` module:

```
n = ['565387674.45', '321772103.48', '321772103.48', '214514735.66', '214514735.65',
     '357524559.41']

from decimal import Decimal

s = sum(Decimal(i) for i in n)

print(s)
```

Prints:

> 1995485912.13

Answer (score -1):

You could use `round(num, n)` function which rounds the number to the desired decimal places. So in your example you would use `round(sum(n), 2)`